# como hacer que gcc genere un archivo binario ejecutable en virtualbox

Tags: c++, c, gcc

para evitar el .exe he puesto al llamar a gcc

```
g++ -c -m64
```

pero no fuciona
igual genera un .exe para una arquitectura de 16 bits

Comment: Ese comando que has puesto **no genera un ejecutable**, sino un archivo de código objeto.

Comment: El flag `-c` le dice a gcc que genere un archivo objeto, como menciona Juanjo, mientras que `-m64` le dice que genere un binario de 64 bits, prueba a remover ambas cosas y cuentanos tu experiencia.

Comment: Para que virutalbox lo ejecute, tendras que tener un SO instalado, en caso de ser linux, tendras que usar las librerias especificas y si es Window igual. Si lo que quieres es que virtualbox ejecute tu rpograma sin SO, entonces tu programa deberia ser un SO, algo complejo.